# Isn't it supposed to be 'it' instead of 'its'?

Tags: syntax, participle-clauses, possessive-adjectives, noun-clause

This is a paragraph from the book 'Less is More: How Degrowth Will Save the World' by Jason Hickel. I am not quite sure whether **its having fallen** is grammatically correct. If I were to use such structure I'd use it as an object pronoun: ''*..because of it having fallen most...*''
Could you shed some light on this confusion of mine over the issue? Thanks in advance ^^

> *Coronavirus is being taken pretty seriously precisely because of **its** **having fallen** most heavily first upon the global North.* The wake-up call it embodies needs so badly to be heard, because the
> slower climate emergency is simultaneous with it – and it poses a
> disproportionate threat to the global South, where it is already
> inflicting mass suffering. So we are in a common crisis with
> differentiated effects. And we must be aware that some governments
> will respond with worsening environmental racism and hidden agendas of
> eco-fascism.

Comment: his breaking the window/him breaking the window. Either subject or object pronouns can be used with a gerund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the traditional position:

A noun phrase is required after the preposition **of.** Thus, **having fallen** should be considered a gerund rather than a participial phrase. Thus, it should be introduced with a possessive adjective—**its**—rather than a noun phrase, **it**. And therefore, the sentence as you found it is correct.

That said, in speech and all but the most formal writing, we are accustomed to subjects and objects that contain a **[nominal form] + [participial phrase]**. Example:

> I don't like John messing around with other women.

Everyone speaks this way.

Strunk and White (for example) forbid such a thing, insisting instead on

> I don't like John's messing around with other women.

But this is pretty stuffy. Very few editors today would insist on this form.

The problem with your sentence is that nasty preposition, **of**. To my ears, anyway, it really needs to be followed by something that sounds more noun-like. **[possessive] + [gerund]** does that.

Burchfield (i.e., Fowler) offers this advice:

> The possessive with gerund is on the retreat, but its use with proper names and personal nouns and pronouns persists in good writing.

He includes **its** with personal pronouns.

Comment: 'its use with proper names and personal nouns and pronouns persists in good writing.' +1

Answer (score 3):

We can use the possessive before a gerund.

> Marjorie’s showing up late for meetings was nothing new
>
> This, in Keller's view, amounts to "a clear presumptive case against
> patriotism's being a virtue and for its being a vice".

[Possessive pronoun before gerund](https://open.books4languages.com/english-b2-grammar/chapter/possessive-pronoun-with-gerund/)